# What Size Screw Holds the Up and Down Shifting Levers on Ultegra Shifter?

Tags: shimano, shifter

There's a screw on the back of my Ultegra (circa 2000) shifters that holds the down shifting (on the right side) inner lever, to the up shifting outer/longer lever. I've long struggled with it loosening, but last week it fell out during a bumpy ride.

I'm having trouble describing it, let alone finding a replacement screw. What size is that screw and what should I call it?

[image: Screw on back of Ultegra shifter]

Answer (score 1):

Surest way: Measure the screw on the other shifter and get a replacement at any place which sells screws. Use screw glue if you already know the screw comes loose easily.

Comment: Ordinarily that would be best, but I'm travelling and wanted to get replacement parts before returning for a weekend ride.

Comment: From the looks it's a dome headed screw 4 or 3mm. As for the length @Michael's advice is the best way to do it.